# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable python

Tags: python

how can I fix this error in this code?

```
while True:
    input1 = input("Hello >> ")

    input = input1.split()

    if input[0] == "Sup":
        print("HI!")
```

Error:

```
input1 = input("Hello >> ")
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: `input = input1.split()` is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `input` as a variable name. Change your code to something like this:

```
while True:
    input1 = input("Hello >> ")

    userInput = input1.split()

    if userInput[0] == "Sup":
        print("HI!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input = input1.split()
```

You're reassigning `input` to be a list value, and it isn't a function anymore.